# c# SELECT with FOR JSON

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to build a web form in ASP.NET that runs  a `SELECT` command on my database and creates a json from it.

This is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.apartments FOR JSON";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            jsonResult.Append("[]");
        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'JSON'.

Comment: What is the `FOR JSON` doing in the query string? Also I would not recommend creating JSON by hand, try object serialization instead (i.e. JSON.NET)

Comment: `FOR JSON` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2016** and not available in earlier versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Lennart Stoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145403/lennart-stoop) Suggested a option is to read all the items to your object and then just serialize to Json with JSON.NET.

```
Nuget package needed NewtonSoft.Json
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Example is

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.apartments";

   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
   {
       connection.Open();
       List<MyObject> myObjectList= new List<MyObject>();
       var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       if (reader.HasRows)
       {
          while (reader.Read())
          {    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
               myObject.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
               myObjectList.Add(myObject);
          }
       }
      var JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjectList);
    } 
}
```

JsonResult is the json object that you want

**EDIT** modified to work with List for beter example

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using old version of SQL Server. JSON feature was added to SQL version 2016.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : SQL Server 2016** adds new support for the JSON format.

Change your SQL and use `FOR JSON AUTO` or `FOR JSON PATH` to get the expected output

Look at the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Format query results as JSON with FOR JSON is available [starting with 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014).
You can read data with `SqlDataReader` and then create `json` manually in C# code (e.g with Json.Net, see [Creating JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm))

Answer (score 0):

The exception error you are getting is due to the syntax error in your query. When using `FOR JSON` keywords you need to end it with either `AUTO` or `PATH`. So, your query needs to be either:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.apartments FOR JSON AUTO";
```

or:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.apartments FOR JSON PATH";
```